# What is a single word that means "made accessible" (not democratized/democratised or simplified)?

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a single word that means "make accessible." The intent is to signal that something inherently complex is being made accessible, without diluting its value and not in a condescending way.

Simplified gives the impression of something being "for Dummies." "Democratized" often gives a sense of something being for the masses, implying that the masses may be crude. Other options like "illuminate" or "demystified" are specifically about cognitive aspects of accessibility. The idea is that just because something is understood, does not mean that it is accessible. For example, mathematical algorithms may be understood but often need to be exposed through usable software to be truly "accessible."

An example would be: Advanced Mathematical Software, [made accessible]

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: A sample sentence that you want to use the word in would be a good start.

Comment: "Advanced Mathematical Software, [made accessible]" sounds to me like the 'Ease of Access Centre' in Windows 10, which provides accessibility options for (partially) handicapped people.  And I don't understand what "truly accessible mathematical algorithms" means.  Maybe someone else will!

Answer (score 2):

There are other ways to solve your question other than looking for a verb, e.g. *Advanced Mathematical Software for Humans*, *Advanced Mathematical Software for Mere Mortals* or *Advanced Mathematical Software for the Uninitiated*.

"Demystified" and "decrypted" have also been used at the end of book titles.